# Cannot access none static methods from static method, Android: getResources() from the type ContextWrapper

Tags: java, android

I have a static class containing overlay items that is called by my main class and then added to an overlay itself.

I can get this to work without image types but I would like to use them, however when I do I get the following error: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type ContextWrapper

I have tried quite a few things to overcome this, by following some guides I have tried to add:

```
     private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Mine.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return Mine.context;
    }
```

I have also ensured that I have the class in question as an application in the manifest.

The class is as follows:

```
    public static ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> array = new ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem>();

public ArrayList<ExtendedOverlayItem> getMine() {
    return array;
}



public static  void addMe() {
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);  //This is the line that doesn't work
    ExtendedOverlayItem myMarker1 = new ExtendedOverlayItem(
            "sample", "sample", new GeoPoint(85.123456,
                    -14.123456), null);
    myMarker1.setMarker(myDrawable);

    myMarker1.setDescription("This is a test description");
    array.add(myMarker1);
}

 private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Mine.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return Mine.context;
    }
```

I have tried adding the following :

```
myMarker1.setMarker(Mine.getAppContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.example));
```

But I still get null pointer errors when calling from the main method, If I leave the images out, it is called correctly.

In the main method I call this class as follows:

```
Mine.addMe();
ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem> thisThing = new   ItemizedOverlayWithBubble<ExtendedOverlayItem>(this, Mine.array, map);
map.getOverlays().add(thisThing);
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked that your context is null or not? have you tried with activity context?

Comment: on which line you get this error?

Comment: The error is on the line:     Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);  If I remove this and the reference to it, everything works. I.e the pointer and description is displayed on the map but I need to have my custom pointer icon.

Comment: I have solved my own problem:    got this to work by creating a helper class to create a static version of context, overriding the onCreate method. It is called where needed and works well. I needed to add it to my manifest. I know this is not ideal but I can now demonstrate my proof of concept tomorrow and remedy these problems afterwards.

Comment: so that means basically your context object was null i guess.... you solution is really bad and you have to come up with good way to do it.
is my answer helped you in you please accept it or vote it if not let it be as is.

Answer (score 0):

In Java static method can not access any non-static method or variable.

`One of the basic rules of working with static methods is that you can’t access a nonstatic method or field from a static method because the static method doesn’t have an instance of the class to use to reference instance methods or fields.`

for more information [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

here is good example  [how to access them](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/why-non-static-variable-cannot-be.html)

Comment: Is there any way around this, or is there anything I could change to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

if you have context set before this line

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);
```

then use

```
Drawable myDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);
```

as add me is static method and can not get context for `getResources()`

EDIT:

`getResources()` is called on context. and in your code you are calling it from a static method but static method can not access nonstatic method of your applications context.
so you made a static object for context and stored your context in it.
but have you checked that the context you set is not null and set before calling above line?

Comment: I have tried modifying that line and adding  private static Context context; but I still get the null pointer error.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: what i want to say is getResources() method is called on instance of context. if before calling addme() if you have set value for your static context object and it is not null then the line given in above answer should work.

Comment: Very sorry for the newbie question but how would I go about writing this ?  I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Regarding your edit, thats the part that I am stuck on.  I'm unsure how to initalise context.  At the moment I just have static Context context.

Comment: never use static until and unless it is really needed.for variables you can use geter seter. and instead of keeping everything static unnecessarily keep it nonstatic and use with instance. Also don't increase number of classes for just keeping variables.

Comment: I get what you're saying and I will look into that once I get this working but I am so close, just need a pointer on how I should go about initialising context in code.

Comment: @user2704807 If you understood what i want to say then research on the same and try to do it on your own. you will learn a lot by self study.

Comment: I got this to work by creating a helper class to create a static version of context, overriding the onCreate method.  It is called where needed and works well.  I needed to add it to my manifest.  I know this is not ideal but I can now demonstrate my proof of concept tomorrow and remedy these problems afterwards.